# Why does the peak value of ripple voltage occurs at T/4

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rectifier

For a half wave rectifier, why does the diode turn off-in other words peak value of ripple voltage occurs- when AC voltage whose period is T starts to decrease from its peak value? I have an intuiton that it must happen a bit after AC signal starts to decrease from its peak value, not at the same time that it has its max value.

Comment: turn off where? what signal? what is T?

Comment: provide some context, please

Comment: Tnx for comments, I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEHdeL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A half-wave rectifier schematic.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Simulation waveforms for Figure 1.*

Notes:

- There is capacitance in the circuit.
- With the arrangement shown the capacitance maintains voltage while the source sine falls away. i.e., The supply voltage is falling faster than the load voltage.
- At (1) the capacitor is fully charged. Note that the current (lower trace) turns off very slightly after \$ V_p \$ probably as the diode continues to conduct a little as its forward voltage drops from 0.7 to 0.5 or so. (Not that the source is still > \$ V_C \$ for some time after the peak.
- The first cycle current is very high as it has to provide inital charge to C1.
- At (2) we can see that the current starts to flow again when \$ V_S > V_C \$.
- At (3) the current stops again at the same point as (1).

> I have an intuition that it must happen a bit after AC signal starts to decrease from its peak value, not at the same time that it has its max value.

How close was your intuition?